# When clicking on a row Cannot find the index or position in listview using arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a listview using following tutorial link http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Outcome of this is, List of Activity as below image
[image]

Now, I want to navigate to different activity screen by clicking on individual row. I do have idea of navigating to next screen, However I'm not able to find the correct position of each row. I don't have much knowledge of android so please bare with my question if it is too silly.

although the code is available on the above link I'm attaching the .xml files and .java. here as well.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"> 

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**listview_item_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

     <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Weather.java**

```
public class Weather {
    public int icon;
    public String title;
    public Weather(){
        super();
    }

    public Weather(int icon, String title) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

**WeatherAdapter.java**

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    Weather data[] = null;

    public WeatherAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Weather[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Weather weather = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[]
        {
            new Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy"),
            new Weather(R.drawable.weather_showers, "Showers"),
            new Weather(R.drawable.weather_snow, "Snow"),
            new Weather(R.drawable.weather_storm, "Storm"),
            new Weather(R.drawable.weather_sunny, "Sunny")
        };

        WeatherAdapter adapter = new WeatherAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);


        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
        listView1.addHeaderView(header);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to attach `OnItemClickListener`

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        // position is index of the row that was clicked
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks mate. Actually I was trying to navigate from whetheradapter.java. thanks it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

where is `listView1.setOnItemClickListener` ? have you set `setOnItemClickListener to listView1?.`and in below code onItemClick have `position`.

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { //do something
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

use setOnItemSelectedListener with list http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html

```
listView1.addHeaderView(header);
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

listView1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
    new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(
            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id
        ) {
             //where pos is your index 
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}

    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way...

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {


    Toast.makeText(context, position+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                Intent go_detail_Activity_Intent= new Intent(context,Target_Activity.class);
                                go_detail_Activity_Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                context.startActivity(go_detail_Activity_Intent);


                        }
                    });
```

I think it help you.